# How to convert an NSDictionary to a JSON object?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm still learning JSON, and using [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.0/). How would I go about taking an NSDictionary and converting it into a JSON object similar to this:

```
{"id":"123","list":"456","done":1,"done_date":1305016383}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the category that SBJSON adds to NSDictionary:

```
NSString *jsonString = [dictionary JSONRepresentation];
```

Just name the keys and values appropriately in the dictionary and SBJSON will do the work for you

Answer (score 3):

There is a JSON-API (since iOS5 and OS X 10.7) in the official iOS-SDK it's called:

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj
                       options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt
                         error:(NSError **)error
```

See Guillaume's post for more information how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020923/261588

Works like a charm.

Comment: Link only answers are not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are using JSONKit instead of SBJSON:

JSONKit also provides a category for NSDictionary

```
NSString *jsonString = [dictionary JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil]
```