# How to create a basic JSON string in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

How can I create a basic JSON string? When I assign the the JSON value in `NSString` I get a semicolon error. How do I create this string without errors? Could you guys help me out? The code is below:

```
NSString *dam= @" {
    "Id": 23, "Ratings": {
    Picnicvanlig: 4, Barn Valning: 2, Badvanling: 5, etc..:3
}, "UserId": santosh@facebook.com
}";
```

Comment: Are you new to all of coding as well?

Comment: Glad to help. You do understand where the error came from? Objective-C (really, C in this case) thinks you're ending the string when it sees the second `"` character... you have to tell the compiler which double-quote characters are part of the string by 'escaping' them with a slash in front.

Comment: Duplicated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape your quoted quotes:

```
NSString *dam= @"{\"Id\": 23, \"Ratings\": {\"Picnicvanlig\" : 4, \"Barn Valning\": 2, \"Badvanling\" : 5, \"etc..\" : 3 }, \"UserId\": \"santosh@facebook.com\"}";
```

Better yet, read [Apple's JSON stuff](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946).

Comment: The string above is still not a JSON string.  All of the keys have to be quoted and so does the email address.