# Create json array in ios

Tags: ios, json

How can i create a json array in below format:

> [{"id":"8"},{"id":"9"}]

Using Nsmutable dictionary we can create an above format,but key should be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate JSON string from NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSDictionary *dict1 = @{
                            @"id" : @"8"
                            };
    NSDictionary *dict2 = @{
                            @"id" : @"9"
                            };

    NSArray *array = @[dict1,dict2];
    NSData *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Output

[
  {
    "id" : "8"
  },
  {
    "id" : "9"
  }
]