# NSDictionary - Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

When running my application I received these errors:

- No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'JSONString'
- Use of undeclared identifier 'insiderUrl'
- No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'JSONString'

Here is the code I executed:

```
- (void)performActionForShortcutItemDuel:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [AppsDelegate RemoveNotificationCenterRequired:@"performActionForShortcutItem"];
    NSDictionary *actionary = userInfo;
    if (actionary != nil && [actionary count]) {
        NSString *name = [actionary objectForKey:@"name"];

        NSDictionary *additionalUserInfo = [actionary objectForKey:@"userInfo"];
        if (name != nil && name.length > 0) {
            BaseNavigationViewController *vc = (BaseNavigationViewController *)self.navigationController;
            NSInteger count = [vc.viewControllers count];
            NSMutableString *urlInfo = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            if (count > 1) {
                id vcL = [vc.viewControllers lastObject];
                if ([vcL isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(name)]) {
                    //Ouvrez l'application que vous voulez sauter sur la page, sans artificielle
                }else{
                    [((BaseViewController *)vcL).navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                    [urlInfo appendString:insiderUrl];
                    [urlInfo appendString:name];
                    if (additionalUserInfo != nil && [additionalUserInfo count]) {
                        [urlInfo appendString:insiderUrlPartition];
                        [urlInfo appendString:[additionalUserInfo JSONString]];
                    }
                    [vc pushViewController:urlInfo];
                }
            }else{
                [urlInfo appendString:insiderUrl];
                [urlInfo appendString:name];
                if (additionalUserInfo != nil && [additionalUserInfo count]) {
                    [urlInfo appendString:insiderUrlPartition];
                    [urlInfo appendString:[additionalUserInfo JSONString]];
                }
                [vc pushViewController:urlInfo];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not declrae the `insiderUrl` anywhere in your code

Comment: Please translate your question to English language.

Comment: Have you define the insiderUrl element in your class if not please declare that variable and its type as well.

Comment: insiderUrl is already declared, i have created an application and every thing was ok and when i was trying to integrate it in another App i received these errors @Ballu

Comment: Also you need to check your brackets {} are in proper scope so that each bracket have its own scope.

Comment: Can you be more in details?

Comment: i have created a CallKit application and it runs correctly and when i was trying to integrate it in my existing chat application i found these errors

Comment: If you want to convert the `NSDictionary` to a JSON string, how I understand, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29447248/1457385) might help.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you. http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/

Comment: You are adding one project in a project. So the app now have two workspace and for each project compilation you need to make dependencies. So go check out that blog and implement that thing your current one.

Comment: Better approach is to create a pod of your current project and use the podfile. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Explanations for your errors are:

1. No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'JSON String'

> -- There is no method named 'JSON String' in NSDictionary class

2. Use of undeclared identifier 'insiderUrl'

> -- You haven't declared variable 'insideUrl' in your code.

3. No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'JSONString'

> -- There is no method named 'JSONString' in NSDictionary class