# How to convert NSDictionary to NSString which contains json of NSDictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

How to convert NSDictionary to NSString which contains JSON of NSDictionary ? I have tried but without success

```
//parameters is NSDictionary

let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

I want convert this NSDictionary Json to NSString in swift

Comment: Your question has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary

Comment: i want to convert NSDictionary Json to NSstring using Swift

Comment: can u please help on this ?

Comment: Best way is to use a framework called SWIFTYJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var error: NSError?
var dict: NSDictionary = [
    "1": 1,
    "2": "Two",
    "3": false
]

let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)

if let data = data {
    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if let json = json {
        println(json)
    }
}
```

Given a `NSDictionary`, it is serialized as `NSData`, then converted to `NSString`.

The code doing the conversion can also be rewritten more concisely as:

**Swift 3:**

```
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
        if let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(json)
        }
    } catch {
        print("something went wrong with parsing json")
    }
```

**Original answer:**

```
if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error) {
    if let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        println(json)
    }
}
```

Note that in order for the serialization to work the dictionary must contain valid JSON keys and values.

Comment: @EyalBenYehuda the most obvious answer to your question is: __just try it__!! You should find any answer you may have by reading [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization), but the answer is yes, it works with nested dictionaries and arrays

Comment: Thanks @Antonio, i did tried before but nothing worked. i finally got it to work( http://stackoverflow.com/a/41091453/1334575 ). thanks to your answer (with a small variation i saw here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial). thanks.

Comment: Thank god, i've been looking for an hour. The NSString idea is perfect.

Comment: Updated for Swift 5: `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)`