# Creating a simple json object from some string data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've read close to a 100 questions on SO but I still haven't been able to figure out how to create a simple JSON object from a set of simple strings. Every attempt ends with unresolved reference.

Eg:

Key1 : value1

Key2 : value2

Key3 : value3

And I want to create a JSON object from the above using Objective C. Thank you.

Edit: This is how I've created the dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"key1", @"val1",
                        @"key2", @"val2",
                        @"key3", @"val3",
                        nil];
```

Comment: Create an NSDictionary containing the data and run it through NSJSONSerializaion.

Comment: `NSString` -> data -> `NSJSONSerialization`. How does your string set exactly look like?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: You should look at [this][1] SO question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary

Comment: I don't have a string as of now. I'm looking for any example that just lets me enter key-value pairs and end up with a json object.  Also, I've managed to create a NSDictionary but converting it to a JSON object seems impossible. I'm trying this `NSString *json_str = [NSString stringFromDictionary:jsonDict];` but stringFromDictionary cannot be found.

Comment: Sigh!!  `stringFromDictionary` is an *old* 3rd party JSON conversion tool, and it's only available if you've installed the corresponding category.  Look at the documentation for NSJSONSerialization.  Please.

Comment: I thought it was a default library. There was no mention of it being a 3rd party tool on the question page.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer doesn't show how to make it out of new strings.

Comment: What he's put in the question is a dictionary even though strings are mentioned in the title. @john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"key1", @"val1",
                    @"key2", @"val2",
                    @"key3", @"val3",
                    nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];
```

This data will json format

Comment: I cannot explain how grateful I am. Thank you.