# How to insert Array inside a Dicionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm creating a drawing application in Swift that can be redrawn on canvas for HTML. Just a prototype. What I need is to get this data in `JSON` format to my database.
I organized everything in arrays and dictionaries.

How can I generate something like this:

```
 {
  "data": [

  {

     "width": 150,

     "height": 200,

     "x": 45,

     "y": 65,

     "id": "line4"

  },

  {

     "width": 150,

     "height": 200,

     "x": 45,

     "y": 65,

     "id": "Shape1"

  },

  {

     "width": 150,

     "height": 200,

     "x": 45,

     "y": 65,

     "id": "line3"

  },

  {

     "width": 350,

     "height": 400,

     "x": 45,

     "y": 65,

     "id": "line2"

  }

  ]

  }
```

Using `Arrays and Dicionaries (and / or Structs`) and then turn into Json.

I tried to create a one Dictionary within an array within another Dictionary.
The data is dynamic, that is the big problem.

help will be appreciated

Comment: So... your question is how to represent JSON structure in statically typed Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr: Array<Any> = []
var dict1: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]
var dict: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]

arr = ["text",1,true]
dict1["arr"] = arr
dict["dict1"] = dict1

// 

var dict2: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]
dict["dict2"] = dict2

print(dict) // ["dict2": [:], "dict1": ["arr": ["text", 1, true]]]

withUnsafeMutablePointer(&dict["dict2"]) { (pdict2) -> Void in
    var pd = UnsafeMutablePointer<Dictionary<String,Any>>(pdict2)
    pd.memory.updateValue(arr, forKey: "arr2")
}

print(dict) // ["dict2": ["arr2": ["text", 1, true]], "dict1": ["arr": ["text", 1, true]]]
```

you can do it. i don't recommend you this approach. you are better to redesign you idea

Answer (score 0):

Here it says how to do it in Objective-C. You can port this solution to Swift.

[Generate JSON string from NSDictionary in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary)

Comment: The problem is Insert Dictionary in Array, inside another Dictionary. But tanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you need swift code?

`var arr: [[key:value]]; // your array`

`var dict1:[key:value] // your dictionary`

`arr.append(dict1) // insert dictionary in the array`

`var dict2:[key : [[key:value]]] //this dictionary will store your array`

`dict2[key] = arr`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that was your question but to create static structure all you have to do is to replace your curly braces with square brackets.

```
let data = [ "data": [
    [

        "width": 150,

        "height": 200,

        "x": 45,

        "y": 65,

        "id": "line4"

    ],
    [

        "width": 150,

        "height": 200,

        "x": 45,

        "y": 65,

        "id": "line1"

    ]
]
]
```

And to serialize it to JSON data:

```
let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
```

And to deserialize back to Swift objects:

```
let data2 = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
```

You might also want to create JSON string from the data:

```
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Or get data from JSON string:

```
let dataFromString = jsonString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Of course you can then convert it to Swift objects using `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Good answer, but still not exactly what I need. The 'data' must be supplied dynamically (for a function or something).

Comment: What do you mean by "supplied dynamically"? To get exact answers you should specify exactly what you need.