# How to store JSON response in string and then store that string locally ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

[enter image description here][1]I get three values from JSON. **How do I store** those three values in `NSString` and **then store those strings locally** i.e on the device? 
I tried `NSUserDefaults` but I'm unable to do it. I've attached the code snippet.

```
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject
                                                   options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! JSONData)
{
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    //_branchId = [responseObject valueForKey:@"branchId"];
    _branchName = [responseObject valueForKey:@"branchName"];
    _branchUri = [responseObject valueForKey:@"branchUri"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_branchId forKey:[responseObject valueForKey:_branchId]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_branchName forKey:@"branchName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_branchUriStore forKey:@"_branchUri"]; // Here the setobject value remains nil only
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

PS: I want to use that stored value in my commonutility also. How to do that as well?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(__fetchBranchUri)/%@",url]]];
```

Comment: can you share the json? we could help more if you do.

Comment: what is the issue your facing ? what didn't work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate JSON string from NSDictionary in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary-in-ios)

Comment: The issue is not the way you are saving your object to userdefaults. I think you're having a problem parsing the values.

Comment: @Murat this is the json response 
{
    branchId = 1;
    branchName = ShellCHN;
    branchUri = "http://192.168.1.145:8181/services/";
    status = success;
}

Comment: @Murat
this is not duplicate of that question, I beg to differ.

Comment: @teja
I'm not able to store the json response in nsuserdefault. 
And if I do, how do i use that stored value in my commonutility file.

Comment: not able to store is always not the right response. When you do that does it crash ? Or when you try to get it back is it nil ? @ShishirAggarwal

Comment: I get nil @TejaNandamuri

Comment: can u print the responseObject ? and did u check is your NSData nil ? or _branchName nil ?

Answer (score 0):

In the else block replace the contents with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[responseObject valueForKey:@"branchId"] forKey:@"branchId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[responseObject valueForKey:@"branchName"] forKey:@"branchName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[responseObject valueForKey:@"branchUri"] forKey:@"_branchUri"]; 

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Edit: Explanation

In your code above the object _branchUriStore is not defined, and may be part of your problem (a simple typo?).  Below, I have updated and condensed your code to remove another problem with your usage of branchId and so that you might recognize from the style that much of what you were trying to do is fine.

Also note that @rmaddie has provided additional refinements below in the comments.

Comment: Use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` unless you have a specific need for KVC. And you don't need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: And how is this different from the code in the question except for combining some lines together?

Comment: There are errors in the apparent logic.  Note the line:

Comment: @rmaddy, There are errors in the apparent logic.  Note the line:  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_branchUriStore forKey:@"_branchUri"];  What is _branchUriStore? Of, course 'synchronize' in not required for each update of NSUserdefaults. But, such depends on the overall app logic, to which we are not privy.    I just fixed the code that I saw.  Perhaps a little too quickly so that I missed the 'value for key'.  I do not think that I should be down voted.  I will be more verbose next time.  I thought this sight was leaner than that.

Comment: You should put the explanation in your answer. Code-only answers don't really help. A good answer explains what was wrong in the OP and a good answer explains how their answer solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you it worked.
And for all who have been asking that my string names are not defined, they are but in .h file.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please "accept" the answer.  I am new on this system and probably need to accumulate "points" to be more effective for others.

Answer (score -1):

Okay here is what you should do.

1- convert your JSONData no NSData

2-Save your NSData in the NSUserDefaults/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did that. But I want to store each value in seperate string, because that value needs to be used everywhere.