# Convert array of dictionaries to JSON Format

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

my api expects to receive JSON data in below form

```
{
  "user_contacts" : [
    {
      "friend_list" : "+928885555512",
      "user_id" : "1"
    },
    {
      "friend_list" : "+925555648583",
      "user_id" : "1"
    },
    {
      "friend_list" : "+925555228243",
      "user_id" : "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

i have created this data through array of dictionaries and its working fine and it is stores in `Data` type Variable. As alamofire requires `[String: Any]` type of parameter so i have to convert that data into desired format so i tried this:

```
let my_dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
```

but when print this `my_dict` before call alamofire. it seems that it is not a correct json see below... with something like that: `__NSArrayI 0x618000271dc0>`

```
["user_contacts": <__NSArrayI 0x618000271dc0>(
{
    "friend_list" = "+928885555512";
    "user_id" = "1";
},
{
    "friend_list" = "+925555228243";
    "user_id" = "1";
},
{
    "friend_list" = "+925554787672";
    "user_id" = "1";
}
)
]
```

So how can i make this correct json form?
what i am doing wrong?

Updated:

```
let updated_User_No :[String:Any]=["friend_list": self.new_convert_telephone_no,"user_id": user_no];

                user_outer_arrary.append(updated_User_No);

                user_inner_array=["user_contacts": user_outer_arrary]
```

it Should be look like this:

```
{
  "user_contacts" : [
    {
      "friend_list" : "+928885555512",
      "user_id" : "1"
    },
    {
      "friend_list" : "+925555648583",
      "user_id" : "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You do have a serialized JSON Object in Swift/iOS. I think Alamofire uses a different data structure;-) You need to convert the ios native data structure to the expected string data structure of alamofire: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary-in-ios

Comment: thnaks! but it does'nt solve my problem. i already hvae json data but it is type      Data Variable. is there any way to store json data in dictionary in [string: any] type.

Comment: user_inner_array is this array ?

Comment: @catalyst check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**Create Structure**

```
let users = ["" : ["user_contacts": [["friend_list":"user_id"],["friend_list3":"user_id3"]]]]
```

**Create Json Object**

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.prettyPrinted) as? [String : AnyObject]
```

Comment: @KKRocls : not works. now it prints: Optional([AnyHashable("user_contacts"): <__NSArrayI 0x610000274600>(

Answer (score 1):

Perform **JSONSerialization** as below:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>
```